# how to reset loop/re-generate random numbers from start or continue in python

Tags: python

I want that if `vys` is bigger than 10 it resets loop and generates another number, if not continue.

```
from random import randint
for i in range(10):
rnd1 = randint(0,9)
rnd2 = randint(0,9)
print([rnd1] + ["+"] + [rnd2])
vys = int(input("Answer:"))
if vys == rnd1 + rnd2:
print ("RIGHT")
else:
print("WRONG")
```

If I use

```
if vys > 10:
break
else:
print([rnd1] + ["+"] + [rnd2])
vys = int(input("Answer:"))
if vys == rnd1 + rnd2:
print ("RIGHT")
else:
print("WRONG")
```

then after `break`, the loop doesn't generate new numbers.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly

Comment: @roganjosh I saw that, however I can't know if the indentation is correct. What if OP wanted the second if statement to be within the else clause of the first?

Comment: Please indent the code yourself, do not leave us guess as to what the interpretation might be. I've formatted your post a bit to give you an idea of how that works. Paste your code, then select the code and use the `{}` button in the toolbar to ensure that the whole block is indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi first i think you should correct  the indentation first. I don't know if you are fine with having a same number generated again in one variable but i think this would help.
first make two lists containing ten random numbers.

```
from random import randint
num_group1=[]
num_group2=[]
while len(num_group1)<10:
    rnd1 = randint(0,9)
    rnd2 = randint(0,9)
    if rnd1+rnd2<10:
        num_group1.append(rnd1)
        num_group2.append(rnd2)
for i in range(10):
    print('what is', num_group1[i],'+', num_group2[i])
    vys = int(input("Answer:"))
    if vys == num_group1[i]+ num_group2[i]:
        print ("RIGHT")
    else:
        print("Lets try again")
```